# UITextView - cannot paste

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have an editable UITextView in an iPad app. I am using it as an area where users can enter a message to be sent. However, in my testing on iOS 4.3.3, I cannot paste text into it although editing works fine.

I have looked through the documentation and can't see where this would be enabled / disabled. How can I allow users to paste into this field?

Comment: usually pasting it's comes standart with UITExtview.Might be a bug in the 4.3.3 witch i doubt , or you changed some functionality. try creating a new project with a standard UITextField and see if it works (I never heard about something like this before please tell me wath happend when you figure it out)

Comment: Further to this: I have tested this on the simulator and it works properly. But on my device it does not.

Comment: Sorry, correction - it only seems to work if you copy text from within the UITextView itself, not from another app (e.g. Safari). And this only works on the simulator - it doesn't offer copy/paste buttons at all on the device.

Comment: (Apologies for keeping on adding comments but this is really strange!) Further testing on the simulator shows that if you start the app the first time, copy/paste buttons appear. But if you put it into the background then bring it forward, it doesn't work! This is looking like an iOS bug but I find it hard to believe.

Comment: (again, sorry for comment stream of consciousness) Testing on the device, I can't get the buttons to appear regardless of whether the app is launched freshly or not.

Comment: ... and yet it works properly on the older iPhone 2G. So in summary: (1) works in simulated iPad only first time launched, (2) does not work on iPad device at all, (3) works fine on iPhone running iPhoneOS 3.2. Bug in iOS?

Comment: I just created a test application with a single view, with a UITextView embedded in it. Copy/paste works properly. So why doesn't it work in my application?

Comment: I don't know you might have accidentally changed something or it's just a setting bug i don't know, my advice is to create a new view with the same name and migrate the code. it might be just a glitch apple is full of them. And one more add, testing on the simulator or on the device are very diffrent. from one another

Comment: I am having a similar issue.  I am running xcode 4 Build 4A304a.  In simulator if App is deleted and tested copy and paste works, try to run it a second time without deleting and it doesn't.

Comment: Please add your observations to the original question instead of the comments.